# django - url blocking

Tags: python, django

I am working on django and came across a problem that is I have a url for example

```
http://domain.com/trial/1/
```

now the problem is that the when i change the url from 1 to 2, if it is not the authenticated user then  the page should not load instead show an error message but instead it displays the page. How can I block the url from the unauthenticated user.

I searched for the solution but did not find it.

Hope you understood the problem

Thanks

Comment: Show us some code. You probably need [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator.

Comment: Are you trying to protect view based on parameter? In my opinion it's possible, but hard to implement. I would extract protected data into dedicated view and protect using one of the rechniques described in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django has [several built-in ways to limit access to views and model resources](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization). From what I can tell of your code, it sounds like you're needing to limit access to a model resource on a per-resource basis.

Assuming that use case, here's an approach:

```
# models.py
class Trial(models.Model):
    # whatever fields
    login_required = models.BooleanField(default=False)

# views.py
def trial_detail(request, id):
    trial = get_object_or_404(Trial, pk=id)
    if trial.login_required and not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('your-login-view'))

    return render(request, 'your-template.html', {'trial': trial})
```

That would give you the flexibility to have some `trial` models that require authentication, and some that don't.

If you also need to lock down access per-user, you can do that via groups, a custom permission, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use @login_required decorator in the view.py file of the related model function.

example:

## views.py

@login_required #login is required one wants to update its profile, this provides security for other user's personal data
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'users/dashboard.html')

Comment: Hey Satyarth, please take some time to familiarise yourself with [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) questions before you write your next answer! Enjoy your stay at SO :)